# C# StringFormat with Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid, string-formatting

I have a DataGrid with every column bound to a value from an array:

```
<DataGridTextColumn x:Name="zoneNum" Header="Number" Width="55" Binding="{Binding ZoneNumber}"/>
<DataGridTextColumn x:Name="zoneStart" Header="Start" Width="100" Binding="{Binding ZoneStart}"/>
<DataGridTextColumn x:Name="zoneEnd" Header="End" Width="100" Binding="{Binding ZoneEnd}"/>
```

I would like to format the value of the "Start" and "End" columns formatted with "0x" + the number in 8 digit - hex format, as what I would get from `"0x" + start.ToString("X8");` 


[image: DataGrid]


How can I get this using StringFormat in the Binding property?

Comment: write your own converter '{Binding ZoneStart, Converter=NumberToHexString}'. I forgot implementation details, but you can find details in google very quickly.

Comment: as @Chris pointed out answering the other question, maybe that's not possible (too lazy to write my own Converter :D) I ended up binding both "Start" and "End columns to a string value.